# is int a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; same with int *a={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Is following two are same in C++ ?

First:

```
    int a[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

and Second,

```
    int *a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Comment: int* a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; doesn't compile...

Comment: but why  const char *pt="123"; can compile

Comment: @jiafu "123" is a string literal. it is an lvalue which means you can take its address and then give it to pt. thats what the code in your comment is doing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first one is an array of integers, the second is a pointer to an integer. So no they're not the same.

The array can be used as a pointer (as arrays decays to pointers to the first element), and the pointer can be used as an array, but for the compiler they are different.

Also, the array will have a size fixed at compilation time, it will be the size of ten integers, and `sizeof` will return `40` (for 32-bit `int` which is the most common). The size of a pointer is the size of a pointer, and not what it points to. So doing `sizeof` on a pointer will return `4` (on a 32-bit machine) or `8` (on a 64-bit machine).

Another also... C++ doesn't have a "literal array", so you can't assign to a pointer like that. You have to allocate memory first and then assign. It can be done in a single step with the new C++11 standard though:

```
int* a = new int[10]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Remember that if you allocate memory like above, you also have to free it:

```
delete[] a;
```

Comment: can we call parametrized constructor in new expression? for e.g how do i allocate an array of std::string using `new`? `new string[10]{"a",..so on}`?

Comment: @Koushik Yes, that will work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

I think that `int *a={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` will fail.

You need to allocate memory for this array and then do the placement

Answer (score 1):

Using both arrays the same way will lead to the same result.

```
printf("%d\n", a[3]);
```

The difference lies into how the compiler sees the two arrays

- the `a[x]` version makes `a` a reference to the data. `a` **is** is the address where data starts
- the `*a` version creates a pointer `a` to an *int* (or several). In this case `a` references a *pointer* to an *int*. This is an extra indirection compared to `a[]`.
- since `*a` is a pointer, you may change its value, while you cannot change `a` value in `a[]`

e.g.

```
 int *a;
 a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
 a = &otherint;
 ...
```

while

```
 int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
 a = malloc(sizeof(int)); // <== ERROR
```

Regarding the initialization, only `a[]` can receive values directly. `*a` needs *int* allocation(s)

```
 int *a = { 1, 2, 3}; // <== ERROR
```

Comment: Try compiling the second example (it's invalid C++...)

Comment: @DietrichEpp added the *initialization* case (initially I thought the question was more about the difference between `a[]` and `*a`. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a1[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

`a1` is an array, so when a goes out of scope memory is freed

otherwise `int *a2={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` `a2` is a pointer (and i think you can't initialize it like that), and even if you do `a2 = a1` the memory is still 'owned' by a1.
You can see that a1 and a2 are different types by using `sizeof`. a2 is only size of a pointer, while a1 is `sizeof(int) * 10`